# Image is not animating to the png sequence function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, png

***functionality:***

When user clicks on the "Tap Here" image button, it will calls the function of "GameStart()", which will ensure that the main image "Star" moves down the page from the top of the page. The star is suppose to animate by using a png sequence logic, its proposed animated movement is to rotate between left and right giving the visual that the "Star" is climbing down a rope.

***What I have done:***

That is to create the `function GameStart()`, that calls on the method of rotation the star left to right when the user taps on the "TAP HERE" image button.

**ISSUE:**

The png sequence is not being called when the star moves down the page. There are 83 png files within the folder "TheStar"

What has gone wrong?? please helpI have attached the code for your reference

```js
function GameStart() {
  console.log("GameStart");
  $("#Tap").click(function() {
    x = document.getElementById('GameStar').offsetTop;
    if (x < bottomStarLimit) {
      for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        if (i >= 0 && i < 10) {
          $("#GameStar").attr("src", "lib/Elements/TheStar/Star_0000" + i + ".png");
          x = x + step;
          document.getElementById('GameStar').style.top = x + "px";
        }
        if (i >= 10 && i < 100) {
          $("#GameStar").attr("src", "lib/Elements/TheStar/Star_000" + i + ".png");
          x = x + step;
          document.getElementById('GameStar').style.top = x + "px";
        }
      }
    }

  })
}
```

```css
#Tap {
  position: absolute;
  width: 600px;
  height: 650px;
  margin-top: 2100px;
  margin-left: 670px;
  outline: 0px;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div id="GamePage" style="width:100%; height:100%;z-index=1;">
  <img id="GameStar" style="position: absolute; top:-6.5em; left:500px; width: auto; height: 150px, z-index:1;" type="image" src="lib/Elements/TheStar/Star_00000.png">
  <input id="Tap" type="image" src="lib/Elements/Tap%20here%20button.png" onclick="GameStart()" />

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a logic error in your code.

Inside your click function `$("#Tap").click(function()`
You use forloops to iterate over your code.
So every time you press the "Tap Here" image button you will iterate over ALL your image files, and you will probably only see the last image inside your folder.

Let me show how your code is now:

- click
- get element
- check if bottom
- go trough all elements
- Add image to element
- Increase counter
- Increase distance on element.

Now what i think you are trying to do is:

- Get element
- When clicked
- Iterate
- Add image to element
- Increase distance on element

Here is some code to help you along:

```js
var player1 = $('#character'); //out player sprite
var iteratecount = 0; //needs to be outside
$('#move').click(function() { //on clicking the button
  iteratecount++; //the same as iteratecount = iteratecount + 1;
  player1.css('top', (iteratecount * 10) + 'px'); //times 10 because it looks better
  //player1.attr("src", "lib/Elements/TheStar/Star_000" + i + ".png");
});
```

```css
#character {
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-color: firebrick;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 105px;
}
.game {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="move">Move</button>
<div class="game">
  <img id="character" href="" />
</div>
```